# How to use new 3d web style symbol ArcGIS map?

Tags: javascript, maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have an issue with the ArcGIS map when using WebStyleSymbol.

To describe the problem I have a list of points and for each point, I have to use a symbol (3d model provided by the library).

to define that I have this const declared:

```
    const treeSymbol = new WebStyleSymbol({
            styleName: 'esriRealisticTreesStyle',
            name: 'Other',
        });
```

and for each point, I'm doing this:

```
            PSS.forEach((item) => {
                const p = {
                    type: 'unique-value',
                    geometry: {
                        type: 'point', // autocasts as new Point()
                        x: item.x,
                        y: item.y,
                        z: item.z,
                    },

                    symbol: treeSymbol,
                };
                const point = new Graphic(p);

                graphicsLayer.add(point);
            });
```

and when I'm trying to use a different symbol than a tree like this,

```
            var powerLinePoleSymbole = new WebStyleSymbol({
                name: 'Powerline_Pole',
                styleName: 'EsriInfrastructureStyle',
            });
```

the element is not loaded anymore.

Here you have a link to a demo: https://codepen.io/raul996/pen/rNQVXdX

Right now is rendered the tree, but if in the p const, you will change the symbol attr from tree symbol to powerLinePoleSymbole the problem will be reproduced, more exactly in the same place the tree will vanish, but nothing will be rendered anymore and I don't know why